# POST works few times

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

I am stuck with this difficult to google error

I am trying to connect MySQL database to android app using POST

[image]

This is my index_app.php

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password = '$password'");
mysqli_store_result($con);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0)
{
    $res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0)
        echo "No User Found";
    else
        echo "password incorrect";
}
else
{
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

When I try to send post request through[hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) , I am getting expected results.But sending them through [requestmaker.com][3] gives wrong results.

Now , when I am trying to get the results in my app , I get results similar to those of requestmaker.com.

Here is code of MyApp

```
public class LoginBtnOnClick extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    String userName, passWord;
    TaskDoneListener taskDoneListener;

    public void setTaskDoneListener(TaskDoneListener taskDoneListener)
    {
        this.taskDoneListener = taskDoneListener;
    }

    public LoginBtnOnClick(String userName, String passWord)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String connect() throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://ezcloud.esy.es/ezCloudWebsite/index_app.php");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        Log.e("asda", "connect: "+userName + " "  + passWord);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("username", userName);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("password", passWord);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        return isToString(is);
    }

    public String isToString(InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = r.readLine();
        while (line != null && !line.isEmpty())
        {
            sb.append(line);
            line = r.readLine();
        }
        Log.d("line", "isToString: "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            return connect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("exception", "doInBackground: "+e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        taskDoneListener.onTaskDone(s);
    }

    public interface TaskDoneListener
    {
        String onTaskDone(String str);
    }
}
```

I am getting

> No User Found

even for correct username and password

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The problem is your PHP file never assigns `$username` or `$password` from the `$_POST` array. Effectively, you are passing empty values into your query. Also -- use prepared statements.

Comment: That's not an error, that's an expected result when no user is found and it's right there in your code. Are you sure there's no extra characters in your columns? `" bob"` and `"bob"` are not equivalent.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I just fixed his code edit which just made that invisibe

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ahh, thanks. I should have checked that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks , I am new to SO.
@ tadman ,I know this and I will increase the security in my next commits.

Comment: **Why are you** SELECTing the same stuff twice?

Comment: You are storing the password in plain text **BAD Developer!!** Look up `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: I know that there are huge security bugs in it and I will increase safety in my next commits but as of now, I just want to know how to get true as output when I am sending username and password as dam and dell respectively.